# characteristic function of standard lognormal distribution

Tags: self-study, lognormal-distribution, characteristic-function

What is the characteristic function of standard lognormal distribution? By "$X$ yields the standard lognormal distribution", I mean $\log(X)\sim N(0,1)$.

I understand that the moments of $X$ is given by $\exp(n^2/2),$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}$. But I don't know how to calculate the characteristic function of $X$.

Comment: Your summation expression for $\phi_X$ (even when it is fixed up to agree with the statement moment formula) does not define a function because it does not converge (except for $v=0$).

Comment: @whuber Yes, that's right. In this case, can we say the characteristic function is not defined?

Comment: The characteristic function is *always* defined.  In this case, its Taylor series does not represent it.

Comment: There is a paper calculating it at https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3550403